# Delphi IXMLDOMDocument2 could not load XML file with % in the file name

Tags: delphi, msxml

I have encountered a strange bug while loading a file into `IXMLDOMDocument2`.  The method `load` returns `False`, if the file name contains `%` and sets `parseError` to:

> The system cannot locate the resource specified.

The file exists and when remove `%` from its name, it works just fine.

Is there any way to load XML file with `%` in its name?

Comment: Include exact code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`IXMLDOMDocument.load()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762722(v=vs.85)#cc-syntax) says that the `xmlSource` source parameter accepts one of the following values:

- a string containing a URL
- `IStream`
- `ISequentialStream`
- `IPersistStream`
- `SAFEARRAY` of bytes
- another `IXMLDOMDocument` instance

You are trying to pass a file name, which the method treats as a URL (the first option in the list above). Character `%` in URLs is reserved for [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding). The `IXMLDOMDocument.load()` method is trying to decode the URL from the string you passed as an argument, which may result in a slightly different file name. The tricky part is that this doesn't happen when the percent character isn't followed by a pair of hexadecimal digits, meaning that: `Test%.xml` will be decoded as `Test%.xml`, but `Test%21.xml` will be decoded as `Test!.xml`, or `Test%4A.xml` will be decoded as `TestJ.xml`.

You should be careful what you pass to the `IXMLDOMDocument.load()` method. You have several options.

### Encode the file name as a URL

This is easy. You can use `TNetEncoding.URL` from the `System.NetEncoding` unit:

```
var FileName := 'C:\test%21.xml';
var Doc := CoDOMDocument.Create;
Doc.load(TNetEncoding.URL.Encode(FileName));
```

### Pass an `IStream` as an argument:

Open a file using `TFileStream` (or `TFile.OpenRead()` from the `System.IOUtils` unit) and wrap it in a `TStreamAdapter` from the `System.CLasses` unit, which implements the `IStream` interface declared in the `Winapi.ActiveX` unit.

```
var FileName := 'C:\test%21.xml';
var Stream: IStream := TStreamAdapter.Create(TFile.OpenRead(FileName), soOwned);
var Doc := CoDOMDocument.Create;
Doc.load(Stream);
```

### Use the `loadXML()` method instead:

There is an [`IXMLDOMDOcument.loadXML()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms754585(v=vs.85)) method that allows you to load XML content from a string. You can use `TFile.ReadAllText()` (unit `System.IOUtils`) to read the content of the file and pass it to the `loadXML()` method.

```
var FileName := 'C:\test%21.xml';
var Doc := CoDOMDocument.Create;
Doc.loadXML(TFile.ReadAllText(FileName));
```

I don't recommend loading XML using this option, because it loads the whole content of the file into memory.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a URI/URL must at least have the format `file:///C:/Windows/explorer.exe`. Not having a [scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) and proper slashes just works by chance - I would never count on it. MacGyver would have known that...